# Aceitar input de usuário sem a necessidade do mesmo apertar enter

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, no método menu(self) preciso aceitar um input de usuário sem a necessidade do mesmo apertar a tecla Enter, somente apertando um numero para escolher uma opção. Sou novo e estou aprendendo, desculpem a bagunça!

```
class CombatRules():
"""Define as regras do combate"""
def __init__(self, character, enemy):
    """Cria um objeto da luta entre o personagem e o inimigo"""
    self.character = character
    self.enemy = enemy

def initiative(self):
    """Verifica quem ataca primeiro"""
    #Verifica quem é mais rapido!
    if self.character.spd >= self.enemy.spd:
        return self.character
    elif self.enemy.spd > self.character.spd:
        return self.enemy

def menu(self):
    """Gera o menu do combate"""
    print(tabulation_lines("Menu"))
    print(tabulation_menu("1 - Atack", "2 - Defend"))
    input("")

def show_combat(self):
    """Mostra situação de combate"""
    print(tabulation_lines("Stats"))
    print(tabulation(self.character.name, self.enemy.name))
    print(tabulation(self.character.classe_name, self.enemy.classe_name, "Classe: "))
    print(tabulation_hp(self.character.live_hp, self.character.hp, self.enemy.live_hp, self.enemy.hp, "Hp: "))
    print(tabulation(self.character.atk, self.enemy.atk, "Atk: "))
    print(tabulation(self.character.defs, self.enemy.defs, "Def: "))
    print(tabulation(self.character.spd, self.enemy.spd, "Spd: "))
    self.menu()

def combat(self):
    """Inicia o combate"""
    if self.initiative() == self.character:
        initiative = 0
    elif self.initiative() == self.enemy:
        initiative = 1
    #while initiative >= 0:
    self.show_combat()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é chato de fazer, por que o "input" mesmo não faz isso, e aí depende de chamar, a partir do Python, as APIs que cada aplicação de terminal disponibiliza - e elas são fundamentalmente diferentes entre Windows e todos os outros sistemas operacionais.

Então, se você realmente quer fazer seu jogo no terminal, é importante usar uma biblioteca para isso, que já disponha de algumas facilidades tanto para ler o teclado, quanto para poder posicionar os elementos do seu jogo, sem ser só uma linha abaixo da outra.

Disclaimer: **o terminal pode não ser a melhor opção para um jogo desse tipo**: você vai ter muito mais liberdade tanto para ler o teclado em tempo real, como o mouse, e posicionar elementos gráficos, se usar uma bibllioteca que dê acesso direto tanto a elementos da tela quanto a teclado e mouse, como o [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/), ou mesmo usando alguma biblitoeca gráfica como Tkinter, GTK+ ou Qt.

Dito isso, há uma biblioteca em desenvolvimento chamada "terminedia" (eu sou o autor), que visa, entre outras coisas, justamente possibilita o desenvolvimento de jogos simples em tempo real no terminal. Tenha em mente que a ideia é mais "poder fazer jogos no terminal" como algo inusitado e divertido com um ar "vintage", do que para "tornar fácil criar jogos para iniciantes, já que não precisam sair do terminal". Não mesmo - fazer um jogo usando a terminedia não é necessariamente mais simples.

Ma dito tudo isso, ela provê vários recursos que podem tornar a vida de uma pessoa bem divertida no terminal, inclusive a leitura de teclado.

Estou pendendo algumas coisas para fazer a release "0.3" - quando ela vai poder ser instalada com "pip install terminedia" - então, no momento é necessário fazer

`pip install git+https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia.git`.

Também não existe ainda uma função que espera uma tecla ser pressionada - a função `inkey` retorna se uma tecla está pressionada no momento ou não. (**ver atualização** abaixo)

Por outro lado, tem várias funcionalidades para posicionar texto exatamente onde você quer (e outros efeitos para ir testando). Você poderá re-escrever suas funções "tabulation" usando `screen.print_at(...)` da terminedia, que permite colocar texto na posição exata da tela. (E, usar efeitos como cores, negrito, piscante, etc... no texto) )

Usando a terminedia, uma forma de obter o primeiro caracter, sem esperar o enter é:

```
import terminedia as TM
import time

def getch():
   with TM.keyboard():
       while True:
           key = TM.inkey()
           if key:
              return key
           sleep(1/30)
```

E, para imprimir texto posicionado e colorido, algo como:

```
with TM.Screen() as sc:
    sc.context.color = "yellow"
    sc.print_at((10, 10), "Título do menu")
```

Uma das coisas que está faltando é uma documentação "passo a passo" - mas as funcionalidades todas estão documentadas aqui:
https://terminedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

E a pasta de "exemplos" do projeto tem alguns programinhas fazendo uso 
das principais funcionalidades:

**Atualização**: A funcionalidade de esperar uma tecla ser pressionada é
sem dúvida algo bem útil. [Então adicionei a função `getch` ao projeto](https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/commit/d11fa2e8d4bfdca2e96875b9848d3c5a15e645df) -
tudo que é necessário para esperar uma tecla ser digitada agora é:

```
import terminedia as TM

tecla = TM.getch()
```

Mesmo se a tecla pressionada for uma especial, do tipo seta para cima,
ou as teclas de função F1-F12, elas podem ser lidas - o objeto especial `TM.KeyCodes` tem os códigos dessas teclas para comparação:

```
import terminedia as TM

tecla = TM.getch()
if tecla == TM.KeyCodes.UP:
   print("Você pressionou 'seta pra cima'")
```

(como as instruções acima são para instalação a partir da master, a função já está disponível. Se o projeto já estiver instalado, passe a opção `-U` para o `pip` para que ele seja atualizado:

`pip install -U git+https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia.git`.

https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/tree/master/terminedia/examples

Answer (score 5):

Com a função `input` isso não é possível. Ela é implementada em C e projetada para armazenar em *buffer* todo o conteúdo digitado até receber o *enter*. O que precisará fazer é interagir diretamente sobre o STDIN do sistema operacional e capturar cada caractere separadamente.

Por sorte, já existem bibliotecas que fazem isso, então não precisará ter o retrabalho. Um exemplo é a [`readchar`](https://pypi.org/project/readchar/).

```py
from readchar import readchar

letra = readchar()
```

Para o ambiente Linux, a implementação desta função é:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Initially taken from:
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/
# Thanks to Danny Yoo
import sys
import tty
import termios


def readchar():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch
```

<sup>Fonte: https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar/blob/master/readchar/readchar_linux.py</sup>

Comment: O problema disso, além da complicação opaca, é que é só para terminais posix - não funciona no windows. Por isso, na minha resposta sugeri uma biblioteca de mais alto nível (por dentr o terminedia faz mais ou menos isso aí também)

Comment: @jsbueno Ela possui também a versão para Windows - pelo menos de acordo com o repositório.

Comment: sim, usar a biblioteca readchar é uma coisa - ela já é uma "biblitoeca de mais alto nível"  - mas,  pinçar o código lá de dentro que faz isso só no Linux é outra coisa.

Comment: (no windows, alias, essa parte é mais simples - na teordia - o próprio Python já disponibiliza o pacote "msvcrt" que tem o "getch" - e é o que é usado na terminedia.

Comment: @jsbueno Ah, sim, a intenção foi apenas mostrar que a implementação no `readchar` interage diretamente com o STDIN, não era a intenção propor como solução a própria função de forma isolada.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode armazenar o que foi digitado pelo usuário em uma variável, se o valor digitado for maior que 0 ele já executa o próximo método ou finaliza a aplicação.

Comment: E como você sugere armazenar na variável o que foi digitado pelo usuário?

Comment: Um breve exemplo:  

numero = input("Digite um número:")

print(numero)

if len(numero) > 0:
 executeProximoMetodo()

Comment: Mas a função `input` aguarda o usuário digitar o Enter para liberar o buffer na memória e é justamente esse comportamento que o autor da pergunta deseja contornar.

Comment: De fato. Estou equivocado, ao invocar o input, automaticamente é obrigatório o uso do enter

Comment: Acho que encontrei uma solução viável. Trata-se de uma lib que simula um KeyPress, chamada pynput, basta instalar e instanciá-la. Segue o link-documentation https://nitratine.net/blog/post/simulate-keypresses-in-python/