# Como verifico se uma tecla foi pressionada em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá eu estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo para fazer uma rolagem de ficha de Dungeons & Dragons, e como muita coisa se modifica na ficha eu queria fazer um esquema onde ao pressionar alguma tecla eu pudesse modificar algum valor, porém não tenho a menor ideia de como começar.
Alguém teria alguma dica ou maneira de o fazer ?

Comment: Eduardo, boa tarde! Você deve exemplificar como essa rolagem funciona, deve adicionar uma tentativa de implementação, caso contrario o moderador vai fechar a sua pergunta. Abraço!

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta duplicada que já tem uma resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429791/aceitar-input-de-usu%c3%a1rio-sem-a-necessidade-do-mesmo-apertar-enter/429854#429854  TL;DR: é chato, pq não depende da linguagem e sim do tratamento de E/S do terminal - então a melhor forma é usar uma lib especifica de terminal. A resposta ligada sugere o "terminedia".